# PHP array_search is very slow - how can i speed up?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, compare

I have two arrays one is a response from an API call where I get information about which email-addresses are already uploaded in the `System -> $array_emails_found`

The other array is data which was uploaded by a `form -> $array_data`

In this use case we need to find out which user is in the system and we need to flag the user data.

Here is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_emails_found; $i++){
    if ($key = array_search($array_emails_found[$i], array_column($array_data, 'Email'))){
        $key = $key + 1;
        $array_data[$key]["InEloqua"] = $array_data[$key]["InEloqua"] . "Y";
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the uploaded file can include for example over 450k users and the response can also deliver such a number and it takes over 2h to be finished.

Comment: Show an example of both arrays.

Comment: `array_column($array_data, 'Email')` doesn't change, so do that outside the loop and save it in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Barmar for your comment, now it works much faster

```
$arraycolumn = array_column($array_data, 'Email');

for ($i = 0; $i < $count_emails_found; $i++){
        $key = array_search($array_emails_found[$i], $arraycolumn);
        $key = $key + 1;
        $array_data[$key]["InEloqua"] = $array_data[$key]["InEloqua"] . "Y";
}
```